# pip3 calls older Python versions on Mac OS X

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyttsx

I am trying to install pyttsx3 using pip3.  When I enter `pip3 install pyttsx3`, I get the following:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ CaptStephan$ pip3 install pyttsx3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/CaptStephan/anaconda/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2630, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group, name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip3') not found
```

I am using MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)

I can install it OK with pip (not pip3) but then it doesn't seem to actually work.  A search shows the solution is to install with pip3, but that gives rise to the above error.

Edit:  updating to Python 3.6.2 corrects this problem, but pyttsx3 does not seem to work correctly.

Comment: Run `head -1 \`which pip3\`` — what Python the `pip3` file uses?

Comment: I suspect it was already obvious, but I am pretty new at Python having only completed the edX MIT programming class and started to work on a robot project.  That said:  MacBook-Pro:~ CaptStephan$ head -1 'which pip3'
head: which pip3: No such file or directory

Comment: Backquotes, not apostrophes: `\`` instead of `'`.

Comment: the result of that is:  #!/Users/CaptStephan/anaconda/bin/python

Comment: Also: MacBook-Pro:~ CaptStephan$ which python
/Users/CaptStephan/anaconda/bin/python
MacBook-Pro:~ CaptStephan$ which python3
/Users/CaptStephan/anaconda/bin/python3
MacBook-Pro:~ CaptStephan$

Comment: What's printed with `/Users/CaptStephan/anaconda/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print sys.path"`? I'd like to understand why `/Users/CaptStephan/anaconda/bin/python3` uses `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

Comment: File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print sys.path
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: In python 3, `print(sys.path)` @phd

Comment: ['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']